# How to show right count of decimal number in mathematica 10

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I have some random number x. It can be 222.1245646 or 3.141562652. How should I show this number to 5 decimal numbers ? I cant use this:

`N[x, 5]` because it shows 5 digits(222.12 or 3.1415).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NumberForm[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html).

This will display number 1.2345678 with 3 precise digits and 4 digits to the right of the decimal:

```
NumberForm[1.2345678, {3, 4}]
```

> 1.2300

You can adjust the second argument to suit your needs. Maybe like this:

```
NumberForm[1.2345678, {99, 5}]
```

> 1.23457

7 is at the end instead of 6 because of rounding.